# Regular Expressions - Back References Confusion

Tags: java, regex

As i am reading Oracle Tutorial for Regular Expressions. I am looking into [Back References](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html#backref) in this article. I understand that once a matching group is found, it is saved in memory for back references. So here is my confusion :-

1. Apart from a simple usage, how is back references significant?
2. How long the back reference stays in memory? I suppose as soon as the regex engine terminates, it should be removed from the memory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common usage for backreference is checking for repetition of something that is not known beforehand.

For example, you want to check whether there are any word being repeated twice in a row. You don't know which word is being repeated - the most you know is the pattern of a word. Backreference allows you to capture a word, then check whether it is followed by another instance of itself.

```
\b(\w+)\b\W+\1\b
```

To know how significant this is, consider the problem where you want to check for repeated character, backreference can do this trivially:

```
(?s)(.)\1
```

If you were to write a theoretical regular expression for this, you would have to enumerate everything in the alphabet:

```
(aa|bb|cc|....|AA|BB|CC...)
```

Backreference tries to match the same text as matched by a capturing group. The engine always keeps track of the text matched by capturing group (for most engines - the last time some text is captured). Therefore, the content of the capturing group stays in the memory (for Java, in the `Matcher` object to be precise) until all references to it is terminated (for Java, when you call `find()`, `matches()`, ... or when `Matcher` object falls out of scope).

Comment: Thanks nhah. The answer was pretty helpful. Thank you very much.